# Configuração VSCode + GIT + Flutter

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, dart, flutter

Senhores, 
Estou a iniciar os estudos em Flutter, fiz a instalação do Flutter, Dart, GIT e VSCode, quando irei iniciar o desenvolvimento o VSCode me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
[undefined] flutter create --ios-language objc --android-language java
'where' n�o � reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa oper�vel ou um arquivo em lotes.
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH. 
exit code 1
```

Poderiam me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

Obrigado

Comment: Qual o sistema operacional?

Comment: Utilizo o Windows 10, 64bits @Marconi

Comment: @Marconi, isso é o que ele me retorna, não que estou criando!

Comment: Reiniciou sua maquina para que as variaveis de ambiente possam ser aplicadas?

Comment: não, pode ser isso! Vou reiniciar! @Marconi

Comment: @Marconi não rolou cara, da o mesmo erro. Já procurei algo na internet e nada!

Comment: Segundo esse issue no github: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15047, você pode adicionar `C:\Windows\System32` a sua variavel de ambiente PATH. Sabe fazer isso?

Comment: @Marconi, acabei de fazer e não deu certo!

Comment: Esquece o VSCode, por um momento, tente rodar no CMD 'git version' para validar sua instalação e variável de ambiente, após, tente rodar 'flutter doctor -v' e coloque a saída na pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não parece ter configurado corretamente na instalação as variáveis de ambiente.

Mostre como você as configurou, mas na dúvida, esqueça o VS Code, por um momento, e tente rodar no CMD:

```
git version
```

Para validar sua instalação e variável de ambiente do Git.

Se estiver tudo certo, tente rodar no CMD:

```
flutter doctor -v
```

E coloque o resultado da saída para vermos.

Se funcionar, sua instalação do Flutter estará correta.

Comment: Boa tarde! A validação do GIT ok, mas no flutter doctor não: 
C:\flutter>flutter doctor -v
'where' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.

Comment: De que forma você fez o download do Flutter? Você deve ter um 'flutter_console.bat', execute e veja o `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: Ingraçado, que quando peço para executar o 'fluter_console.bat' abre a janela CMD e fecha em seguida! Baixei ele diretamente do site  https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows

Comment: Quando acesso o 'flutter_console.bat' ele só abre se eu 'executar como administrador' e me da a seguinte mensagem quando digito 'flutter doctor -v', C:\flutter>flutter doctor -v
'where' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.

Comment: Sua instalação está corrompida ou com algum problema. Faça o seguinte, remova o que você criou e faz a instalação pelo GIT clone, exatamente como o site que você passou recomenda.

Comment: Beleza, farei novamente a instalação e retorno aqui em seguida! Obrigado

Comment: cria a pasta 'C:\src\flutter', acessa ela via cmd 'cd C:\src\flutter', e faz um git clone do repositório do Flutter. 'git clone -b stable https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git'

Comment: Boa noite, segui os passos mas me retorna a seguinte mensagem: C:\src\flutter>flutter doctor
'flutter' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

Comment: Boa noite, agora me retorna o seguinte erro: C:\src\flutter>flutter upgrade
Checking Dart SDK version...
'PowerShell.exe' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.
Error: Unable to update Dart SDK. Retrying...

Comment: Bom dia! Deu certo a instalação, segui seu conselho, desinstalei tudo e reinstalei novamente, e adicionei os caminhos em variáveis de ambiente: C:\src\flutter\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\System32;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\crist\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin - Muito Obrigado

Comment: Show! Pelo visto você estava até sem as variáveis do windows no Path

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi assim:

eu abri o arquivo flutter_console.bat como adm pra executar o comando "flutter doctor"

mudei as variaveis do windows

C:\flutter\bin; C:\Windows\System32

%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

System Variables

C:\flutter\bin

C:\Windows\System32\

Answer (score -2):

Add below path to Environment variable

User Variables

C:\flutter\bin; C:\Windows\System32

%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

System Variables

C:\flutter\bin

C:\Windows\System32\